# what does " The 'let! ... and! ...' construct may only be used if..." mean, in F#

Tags: f#

I have this code:

```
async {
    ...
    let! s0 = ZonesDatabase.upsertConsolidationZonesAsync       credentials exchangeName instrument interval zones
    and! s1 = FairPricesDatabase.upsertFairPricesAsync          credentials exchangeName instrument interval fairPrices
    and! s2 = LiquidityLinesDatabase.upsertLiquidityLinesAsync  credentials exchangeName instrument interval liquidityLines
    and! s3 = EventsDatabase.insertEventsAsync                  credentials exchangeName instrument interval events
```

These are 4 write events to 4 distinct tables in a db. If one of them fails, it is acceptable for the other operations to complete successfully.

But when trying to compile this, I get the following error:

> [FS3343] The 'let! ... and! ...' construct may only be used if the computation expression builder defines either a 'Bind4' method or appropriate 'MergeSource' and 'Bind' methods

Does that mean that the async builder wasn't updated after the introduction of 'and!' ?

Comment: Correct, async does not support `and!`

Answer (score 0):

There is no implementation of `BindN` or `MergeSources` methods in `FSharp.Core` yet, so you have to implement it yourself. For sequential execution the implementation might be something like this:

```ml
type AsyncBuilder with
    member _.Bind2(a1: Async<'T>, a2: Async<'U>, f) = async {
        let! r1 = async {
            match! a1 |> Async.Catch with
            | Choice1Of2 ok -> return Ok ok
            | Choice2Of2 err -> return Error err
        }
        let! r2 = async {
            match! a2 |> Async.Catch with
            | Choice1Of2 ok -> return Ok ok
            | Choice2Of2 err -> return Error err
        }
        return! f (r1, r2)
    }
    
    member self.Bind3(a1: Async<'T>, a2: Async<'U>, a3: Async<'W>, f) = self.Bind2(a1, a2, fun (r1, r2) -> async {
        let! r3 = async {
            match! a3 |> Async.Catch with
            | Choice1Of2 ok -> return Ok ok
            | Choice2Of2 err -> return Error err
        }
        return! f (r1, r2, r3)
    })
```

Also, you might want to look at the discussion of default implementation of these methods in [F# GitHub repository](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/discussions/11043).